# how to display html content in a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, exchangewebservices

What I want to do is to create a reply page in my email application, which the original email content shows in bottom, user could enter their reply message on top.I know I can display html content in a DIV by using div.InnerHtml property. But in a div user cannot input new content. Is that possible that HTML content could be displayed in a textbox? If not, any other option? My development environment is Asp.net C#, I use EWS to communicate with exchange server. Thank you.

Comment: `<div contenteditable> ... <div>` ?

Comment: OMG!OMG!OMG! Man, you should post it as an answer! Awesome! I mean HTMLEditor is a solution, but yours is pretty easy to implement.^_^

Comment: But how to get the div content after you edit it. I use div.InnerHtml, it always returns original content without new content I just input.

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xSwY7/ (edit the DIV and then click on the button below it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HTMLEditor](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx) control.

Comment: @Steven nope. I hate the min characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could encode the content... e.g. `<html>` to `&lt;html&gt;`

Comment: If you need a real editor then Yuriy is right. I have used it myself and it works perfectly, also quite simple to implement.